# Add google trends in react

Tags: reactjs, google-trends

How do you add components such as charts in google trends in reactjs?

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    const that = this
    const keyword = "your keyword"

    conts script = document.createElement("script")
    script.src = "https://ssl.gstatic.com/trends_nrtr/760_RC08/embed_loader.js"
    script.async = true

    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.trendsWrapper1).appendChild(script)

    script.onload = function () {
       trends.embed.renderExploreWidgetTo(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(that.refs.trendsWrapper1), "TIMESERIES", {"comparisonItem":[{"keyword":keyword,"geo":"","time":"today 5-y"}],"category":0,"property":""}, {"exploreQuery":"q=%2Fm%2F0rfgxy2","guestPath":"https://www.google.co.uk:443/trends/embed/"})
    }

}
```

I tried this and didn't work. Please try to suggest a much easier method than this as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the embed_loader script out side of react (like any other 3rd lib code)

At the component, run the trends.embed command.

```
var Trends = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
   trends.embed.renderWidget("US_cu_mqCQGFwBAABWOM_en", 
   "fe_line_chart_309e703b-7d68-4baa-8dc9-c12e2f9defc3", 
   {"guestPath":"https://trends.google.com:443/trends/embed/"});  
  return (
    <div>must return something :/</div>
  )}
});
```

[Here is an example](https://codepen.io/guyogev/pen/xpeVLX?editors=1010)